# how to make a child to re-render by other child action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an application like

```js
export default function App(props) {
    return <>
        <FooList />
        <hr/>
        <CreateFoo />
    </>;
}
```

my `FooList` is a class like

```js
export default class FooList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            foos = []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('/getFooListPath').then(res=>{
            this.setState({foos=> res.data});
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const mapedFoos = this.state.foos.map((foo, i)=><li key={i}>foo</li>);
        return <ul>mapedFoos</ul>;
    }
}
```

and `CreateFoo` is like

```js
export default function CreateFoo(props) {
    const [txt, setTxt] = useState("");
    const handleChange = (event) => setTxt(event.target.value);
    const handleChange = () => {
        Axios.post("/createFooPath", txt).then(res=>{
            // TODO : maybe calling some method here
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
    return <>
        <input type="text" onChnage={handleChange} />
        <button onClick={handleClick} >create</button>
    </>;
}
```

problem is that i want to re-render FooList after i successfully created foo.

i already thought about moving `foos` to parent `App`, and send it to `FooList` as props. but i want to make `FooList` independent from parent, so wherever i want to use it, it show me current `foos` on database

Comment: You need to add your axios logic `App` component.In that way if any props changed both component is going to render again

Comment: Seems like lifting the state up to shared parent would work well.

Comment: Please see [Lifting State up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for this.

Comment: @ksav ... if i do this so wherever i want to use FooList i have to fetch foos again in parent of it

Comment: `FooList` can render based on prop `foos`

Comment: @DrewReese i already thought about moving foos to parent App, and send it to FooList as props. but i want to make FooList independent from parent, so wherever i want to use it, it show me current foos on database

Comment: @ShubhamVerma .... i already thought about moving foos to parent App, and send it to FooList as props. but i want to make FooList independent from parent, so wherever i want to use it, it show me current foos on database

Comment: *Something* needs to coordinate when a new Foo is create (POST'ed) to get `FooList` to  refetch... Seems you can update *some* state in `App` that is passed to `FooList` to "kick" it into fetching data. Another option is polling in `FooList`, but that is very sub-optimal.